# Bot is not waiting for the message

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

I'm trying to make the bot wait for a specific message(from a specific author and some specific things) But the bot is just waiting for any message and it makes the command.

Here's the function:

```py
async def check(message):
    if type == "netflix":
      c.execute("SELECT price FROM netflix")
      neprice = c.fetchall()
      netprice= neprice[0][0]
      netfprice = netprice*amount
      nettax = await tax(args=netfprice)
      try:
        return message.mentions[0].id == 994347081294684240 and message.author.id == 282859044593598464 and int(nettax + netfprice) in message.content
      except IndexError:
        return False
```

Here's where I call the function:

```py
      await bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=60)
```

Here's the full command:

```
@bot.slash_command()
@discord.ext.commands.cooldown(1,60, discord.ext.commands.BucketType.user)
async def buy(message, type: str, amount:Optional[int]):
  if amount == None:
    amount = 1
  if amount < 0:
    await message.respond("You cannot buy negative amount of accounts")
  member = message.author
  con = sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite")
  c = con.cursor()
  async def check(message):
    if type == "netflix":
      c.execute("SELECT price FROM netflix")
      neprice = c.fetchall()
      netprice= neprice[0][0]
      netfprice = netprice*amount
      nettax = await tax(args=netfprice)
      try:
        return message.mentions[0].id == 994347081294684240 and message.author.id == 282859044593598464 and int(nettax + netfprice) in message.content
      except IndexError:
        return False
    elif type == "spotify" or "crunchyroll":
      c.execute("SELECT price FROM spotify")
      spotiprice = c.fetchall()
      spotprice = spotiprice[0][0]
      newspot = spotprice*amount
      spotytax = await tax(args=newspot)
      print(spotiprice[0][0])
      try:
        return message.mentions[0].id == 994347081294684240 and message.author.id == 282859044593598464 and int(newspot + spotytax) in message.content
      except IndexError:
        return False
if type == "netflix":
    c.execute('SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS "count" FROM netflix GROUP BY price')
    netamount= c.fetchall()
    print(netamount[1])
    if netamount[0][3] < amount:
      await message.respond(f"We do not have this amount of accounts in the stock")
    else: 
      c.execute("SELECT price FROM netflix ")
      netfprice = c.fetchall()
      netprice = netfprice[0][0]
      newnet = netprice*amount
      withtax = await tax(args=newnet)
      embed = discord.Embed(title="transfer",description=f"Please transfer :{newnet + withtax}")
      embed.add_field(name=f"c <@994347081294684240> {newnet + withtax}",value="**Copy paste the message for no error**")
      embed.set_footer(text=f"Sidtho Host. | Requested by - {message.author}")
      print("Sent embed, Waiting for receiving the credits")
      await message.respond(embed=embed)
      await bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=60)
      c.execute("SELECT email, password FROM netflix")
      netres = c.fetchmany(size=amount)
      # print(netres)
      embed = discord.Embed(title=f"حساب {type}", description="")
      embed.add_field(name="Sidtho Host.",value=" ",inline=False)
      for thisamount in netres:
        try:
          email = thisamount[0]
          password= thisamount[1]
          embed.add_field(name=f"Email: {email}", value=f"Password: {password}", inline=False)
          # print(f"The email is {email} \n The password is {password} 
        except TypeError as err:
          print(f"Gave A TypeError. Where {err} ")
      await member.send(embed=embed)
      c.execute("DELETE FROM netflix WHERE email=? AND password=?",(email, password))
```

There is no traceback So no error.

Please note that the check function is a Function, not a command.
and the await bot.wait_for is on a command.

Please note too that `type` is a value that the user will give to the bot, and its not the python built.

Comment: I've not used discord.py or pycord or what-have-you, but what looks off is `if type == "netflix`. `type` is a python built in and has nothing to do with the message being passed into your `check()` function. Perhaps there is a `message.type` property you meaning to check instead?

Comment: No. `type` is a value that the user is going to give when he executes the command.

Comment: Where is `type` assigned? I don't see it in the function, is it a global variable? Regardless, you shouldn't have variable names that conflict with reserved keywords in python.

Comment: `type` is assigned in the command. I'm sorry I didn't add it before but wait I will edit my post and add it now.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you wrote `await message.respond(...)`.

There isn't a `respond()` function in both discord.py and pycord, as far as I know. Try changing it to `reply(...)` and see if it works.

Comment: There is `.respond()` and It's perfectly working with other code..

Comment: @Whilesidal could you point to a documentation that has the `respond()` function?

Comment: following [ThisLink](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api/application_commands.html) You can find in the code that there is `await ctx.respond()` in the example.

Comment: @Whilesidal in Pycord, the `respond()` function is only used for the ctx (Context) object. For a message, it is `message.reply()`. [(Reference)](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api/models.html#discord.Message) - as you can see in the `discord.Message` class, only the `reply()` function exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
async def buy(message, type: str, amount:Optional[int]):
      #type here the stuff that u want make before the check
      def check(m):
                return m.mentions[0].id == 994347081294684240 and m.author.id == 282859044593598464 and int(nettax + netfprice) in m.content 
            try:
                response = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=30.0)
            except:
                #here u can send a message when the time is done
                message.send("timeout")
                return
```

> so yeah it should look like this u take the response and run any checks on or save to db.